# Mongodb changestream pipeline query does not work

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb, bash, changestream

My document is like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6257a55d04bf2167733f5b72"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "CustomerName": "John",
        "CustomerID": "28374",
        "LoanID": "82349327409234"
    },
    "type": "Record"
}
```

My changestream watch is like this:

```
var watchCursor = db.transactions.watch([ {$match: {"attributes.LoanID": { $exists : true }}} ]);
while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
   if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
      print(JSON.stringify(watchCursor.next()));
   }
}
```

But the change stream can't find this document. Any thoughts? Note that my search query is after
the nested field inside attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the reason is because the changestream event document is not an exact copy of the actual document.

In case of an update, the actual document resides in `updateDescription.updatedFields` and in case of an insert it resides in `fullDocument` field.

Ref:
[Mongodb change-events](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/)